# How to use a same step in different features in cucumber selenium?

Tags: kotlin, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

In my automation, I have same steps for different features. For example when I'm checking if a user is logged in or not.

Seems like I cant defined the same steps in different class, or it would result in error. So if I only use the step definition in one of the class, the other class would receive an error cause the driver is not yet initiated.

Lets say I have below features

A.feature

```
Feature: A

Given i am logged in
When Step A
Then Result A
```

B.feature

```
Feature: B

Given i am logged in
When Step B
Then Result B
```

A.kt

```
public class A {
    private lateinit var webDriver

    @Before
    fun init(){
    //init webDriver for class A
    }

    @Given("i am logged in")
    fun logInChecking(){
        driver.get("") // this will work for feature A, but will error in feature B
    }
}
```

B.kt

```
public class B {
    private lateinit var webDriver

    @Before
    fun init(){
    //init webDriver for class B
    }

    //@Given("i am logged in") I cant define the steps in here (duplicate steps)
    //fun logInChecking(){
    //    driver.get("") // this will work for feature A, but will error in feature B
    //}
}
```

Here is my cucumber task to run the `./gradlew cucumber`

```
task("cucumber") {
    dependsOn("assemble")
    dependsOn("compileTestJava")
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
            classpath = cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.get().output + sourceSets.test.get().output
            args = listOf("--plugin", "pretty", "--glue", "features", "src/test/resources")
        }
    }
}
```

How should I do this? I tried with class extension, also didnt work. seems like cucumber cant use something like base class then use the extension class.

Comment: If I have answered your question, please make sure to click on the checkbox next to my answer. I will greatly appreciate additional feedback as well by commenting under my answer.

Comment: Can you include your `TestRunner` in this example?

Comment: @hfontanez what is `TestRunner` ? seems like I dont have it in my source code. I only have features and classes

Answer (score 1):

Your class organization does not need to align 1:1 with your features. While this might seem logical, it might be better to organize your classes by function. For example, you can have a class dedicated to user authentication. For example:

```
public class AuthenticationActions {

  @Given("I am logged in") 
  public void loginCheck(){...}

  @Given("logout") 
  public void logout(){...}

  @Given("login") 
  public void login(){...}
}
```

---

```
public class OtherStuff {

  @Given("I want to do other stuff")
  public void doOtherStuff() {...}
}
```

Then in this case, no matter which feature needs to call a method, no collision (conflict) will occur. Remember, the way Cucumber resolves this is by going to your "feature" package, and use reflection to find an expression that matches the step string. For that reason, only one instance of that pattern must exist in the package or subpackages. It is the same thing as having a method with the same name and signature in a class hierarchy. You cannot do that.

If you need to have *similar* functionality in distinct steps, then you need to either 1) name the step slightly different, or 2) have a different parameter list in your step definition. For example:

```
Feature A:
Given i am logged in

Feature B:
Given i am logged in "hector"
```

Since one step requires zero arguments and the other requires one argument, you can have these steps defined in your class(es) as follows:

```
public class AuthenticationActions {

  @Given("I am logged in") 
  public void loginCheck(){...}

  @Given("I am logged in {string}") 
  public void loginCheck(String user){...}

}
```

Bottom line: When it comes to step definitions, the same rules for creating methods in a class hierarchy apply. In some cases where similar names are needed, you need to be creative. Method (step) overloading is one way to do it. And you definitely do not need 1:1 alignment between your step definition classes and your feature files.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but this is still not answering, how can I use the selenium driver if I separate the functions in different classes?

Comment: @Mark Classes Classes have nothing to do with this. Your `CucumberOptions` must specify the `glue` which is the name of the package that contain your step definitions. You can have your methods in one or a million classes. It doesn't make any difference. When a step is invoked, the driver will go to the location specified by the value of `glue` and will find the matching step, regardless of which class contains it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But I am wondering, why would the "Given i am logged in" would work with the `Feature A`, but not work in `Feature B` and resulting of `driver not initialized` exception. Do I miss something with my setup?

Comment: @Mark My answer is to address the "duplicate step" problem. This "driver not installed exception" might be a symptom of another (perhaps related) problem. But that is a second question altogether. You cannot tag two methods with the same annotation value.

Comment: Sorry, actually that is my root issue. If it's only the duplicate step, I could just put it in a separate class, or 1 of the classes. but if I separate it, then I cannot use the same `driver` with the other steps. 1 driver means 1 tab in a browser. In some steps, I need to use the same `driver`, so that it would continue the steps in the same browser tab. If i need to create a different naming rules for "i am logged in" just so that I could use the same `driver` in the same class, I think it might not be a proper solution.

Comment: @Mark what I mean is that you have two problems. Stackoverflow's policy is one problem per question. You'll need to create a separate question describing the problem, error messages (if any), and the code you ran; even if the code is the same. You need to make duplicating the issue easier for people trying to help you. This question specifically addresses the duplicate step issue, which I answered.